# How to read .xml file in openCV C++

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I created an .xml file with Excel and tried to read it into opencv with: 
  **

```
FileStorage fs;
fs.open("mean_200.xml", FileStorage::READ);
fs["mean"] >> mean;
fs.release(); 
    cout<<"Mean image loaded\n";
```

**
It compiled and ran but gave me an ERROR: 'Attribute name must be followed by '=' '

Any ideas to help?

Comment: Probably there is a error inside the xml file, post it. And if it is to large try to make a minimal version.

Comment: It's quite a long file, but begins like this:
** 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">-<Row><Column1>84.99</Column1></Row>-<Row><Column1>85.16</Column1></Row>+<Row>-<Row><Column1>84.965</Column1></Row> 
**

Comment: Post it in http://pastebin.com/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Am9EFWg4

Comment: I just think it is not easy to port a excel .xml file to a format opencv expects. Take a look at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html and open the xml file you'll see major differences. Although in the xml-file you've posted I don't see an attribute with a missing "=" before it's data. Sofar the error seems misleading.

Answer (score 0):

To read an xml in C++, you either read it line by line, e.g.:

```
getline(file,line);
size_t found=line.find("object");
if (found!=string::npos)
{ //Object found. Do stuff.
}
```

or use a library for that purpose like [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/).

Comment: The question was how to do it in OpenCV, and there is code with `FileStorage` class.

Comment: Yes, you are quite precise. Downvote was too strict though. I've done various parsings with `getline()`.